# Filling the password entry in Android browser

Tags: android, api, browser, passwords

Is there any API (presumably it would be the Android API since the browser doesn't seem to support extensions) for filling password fields in general, and android browser password fields in particular?

Specifically, I want to write an equivalent to [passhash](http://wijjo.com/passhash/) for Android browser. This would mean when the user is required to enter a password in a web form (say), rather than doing so they would enter some password using, let's say, a custom keyboard app, which then maps that into some other password that is the inserted into the password field. Basically, it's a way of filling the password fields using some other mechanism than the default keyboard app.

Is this is possible? I understand that Lastpass does this (though I haven't tried it, so I could be wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any API (presumably it would be the Android API since the browser doesn't seem to support extensions) for filling password fields in general, and android browser password fields in particular?

Not really.

> I understand that Lastpass does this (though I haven't tried it, so I could be wrong).

They are using accessibility APIs for this for standard Android apps. Web browsers will be a mixed bag as to whether the accessibility APIs will work or not. Bear in mind that there are many Web browsers for Android. Also note that the relevant accessibility APIs only exist on Android 4.3+.

Comment: That's a bit of a pain. Is it possible for a keyboard app to know when inserting into a password field?

Comment: @HenryGomersall: Not that I am aware of.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it'll be Firefox or Dolphin browser then until Google allows extensions in the browser.